# DialogFlow CX throwing "Regular expression match too broad" error for REGEX ENTITIES

Tags: regex, dialogflow-cx

I try to define a DialogFlow CX custom entity for values like e.g. "0.23" using the Regex option and entering the following Regex: `[+]?([.]\d+|\d+([.]\d+)?)`

But DiglogFlow CX would not accept this Regex and throw the error `Validate entity failed because of the following reasons: Regular expression match is too broad: [+]?([.]\d+|\d+([.]\d+)?)`

I have this issue with many, many other Regex examples. Why can't I use Regex like the one above? This is not broad at all, right? This perfectly defines a very specific number format which I need. It seems I am somehow not understanding this all all...?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *"Regular expression match is too broad."* error occurs if the [regular expression](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/cx/docs/concept/entity-regexp) that you defined has a pattern that is not specific enough - which might result in it matching virtually anything or matching unlimited values with the same pattern.

For example, your regular expression `[+]?([.]\d+|\d+([.]\d+)?)` can match multiple numbers with the sample pattern:

- 2.34
- 0.123 231.1231 .145 …

For your use case, you may consider using the @sys.number [system entity](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/cx/docs/concept/entity-system) instead. The @sys.number matches any ordinal and cardinal numbers including decimals.

However, if you prefer using a regular expression entity, you can use the one of the following syntax for accepting decimal numbers:

- `^[+]?([.]\d+|\d+([.]\d+)?)$`

  - ^ means beginning of text
  - $ means end of text

    *Note: The ^ and $ symbols prevent the regular expression from matching unlimited values with the same pattern. Ex. 23.23 13.31 23.12 0.113 …*
- `[0-9]*[.][0-9]+`

  - [0-9]* means that it will match one or more digits from “0” to “9” or none
  - [.] means that it will only match “.”
  - [0-9]+ means that it will match one or more digits from “0” to “9”

The syntax above will match these formats:

- 0.23
- .23
- 123.4567

Dialogflow uses the [Google RE2 syntax](https://github.com/google/re2/wiki/Syntax) for Regular Expression.